# Symfony2 doctrine nested join relation

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I want to do something like this with my Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Parent` P 
LEFT JOIN `child` C ON P.id = C.parentID
LEFT JOIN `childOfChild` CoC ON C.id = CoC.cID
WHERE P.id = 1
```

I try this QueryBuilder but don't work.

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('P,C,CoC')
    ->from('DspAppsBundle:Parent', 'P')
    ->leftJoin('P.child', 'C')
    ->leftJoin('C.childOfChild', 'CoC')
    ->where('P.id = 1')
    ->getQuery();
```

Can somebody tell me, how I cam make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try something like this (you can replace getResult() with getSingleResult() or whatever suits you):

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('P,C,CoC')
    ->from('DspAppsBundle:Parent', 'P')
    ->leftJoin('DspAppsBundle:Child', 'C', 'WITH', 'P.id = C.parentId')
    ->leftJoin('DspAppsBundle:ChildOfChild', 'CoC', 'WITH', 'C.id = CoC.cId')
    ->where('P.id = 1')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: yes. thanks. work for me. sorry slow respon. @piyushsingh

Comment: Awesome. No worries! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the query in order to get the results.

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('P,C,CoC')
    ->from('DspAppsBundle:Parent', 'P')
    ->leftJoin('P.child', 'C')
    ->leftJoin('C.childOfChild', 'CoC')
    ->where('P.id = 1')
    ->getQuery();
$result = $query->execute();
```

What do you get in `$result`?

Comment: i do `return $query->getArrayResult();`
but not work.

Comment: What do you get in result? Do you get a null?